# How to read multiple .nc files and export it to different respective .csv files?

Tags: r

I have many .nc (netcdf) files, each file representing rainfall at hourly interval. I need to convert multiple .nc files to multiple respective .csv file. Using R, I am able to convert one .nc file to .csv successfully but I want to convert multiple files at one time.

I have successfully converted one .nc file to .csv file. For conversion of multiple files at one time, I have tried to stack all the files together using 'stack' command and then convert the to .csv using 'write.csv' or 'writetable' but it showed error and didn't work.

Code to convert one .nc file to .csv is as follows:

```
library(raster)
nc.brick <- brick(file.choose())
nc.df <- as.data.frame(nc.brick[[1]], xy=TRUE)
write.csv(nc.df, file.choose())
```

As an output, I have got a .csv file with three columns, one representing latitutde, second-longitude and third-rainfall value. I want such similar multiple .csv files to be converted from multiple .nc files at one go. So, is there any way to convert multiple .nc files to multiple .csv files respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a loop over files in a directory. So rather than using file.choose() which require manual choosing of files, you can make a vector of the files in your directory.

```
rm(list = ls())
install.packages(“raster”)
install.packages(“ncdf4”)
library(raster)
ptf <- "/path/to/nc/files"
setwd(ptf) # change your working directory
lf <- list.files(pattern="[.]nc$") # list of files ending in .nc
for(i in lf){
  nc.brick <- brick(i)
  nc.df <- as.data.frame(nc.brick[[1]], xy=T)
  write.csv(nc.df, sub("[.]nc$",".csv",i)) # write to the same file name substituting .nc to .csv
}
```